# SQL join with 2 columns, if exist then column 1 else column 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am still a beginner in SQL so this question might be quite simple for sifus.

I have 2 tables at the moment:

Table 1 (tab1)

```
| ID | Name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  |       |
|    | David |
|    | John  |
```

Table 2 (tab2)

```
| ID | Name  | Mood
+----+-------+-------
| 1  |       | Happy
|    | David | Sad
| 3  | John  | Angry
| 3  | John  | Angry
```

Expected output:

```
| ID | Name  | Mood
+----+-------+---------
| 1  |       | Happy
|    | David | Sad
|    | John  | Angry
```

What I'm trying to do is left join Table 1 with Table 2 when if ID exists, search for ID in table 2 and get mood, else search for Name from table 1 to table 2 and get mood.

This is what I got for now:

```
Select tab1.id, tab1.name, tab2.mood 
From tab1
Left Join tab2 on coalesce(tab1.id, tab2.id) = coalesce (tab1.name, tab2.name)
```

This will work if tab1 and tab2 have exact same structure on ID and name, but for third example it is taking tab1.name = tab2.id and it's not getting the right result. Can anyone please point me to the right direction?

One thing to note is that my `count(*)` has to be exactly as tab1, so if there's duplicates in tab2 I will only take the first result that matches

Comment: Duplicates would be an issue you'd have to have a strict rule for. (i.e. What result would you want in the case of duplicates? 'First result that matches' is too vague and doesn't mean anything.) Also, could there be duplicates on both ID and name? Or different names for a given ID?

Comment: In tab2 there will be duplicated entries but using a distinct we will be able to filter out the rest and get the unique value. Either first or distinct will do for this case. I have edited the tab2 to have a clearer picture

Answer (score 0):

May be a simple `OR` is what you want?

```
SELECT tab1.id,
       tab1.name,
       tab2.mood
       FROM tab1
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tab2.id,
                                       tab2.name,
                                       tab2.mood
                                       FROM tab2) tab2
                      ON tab2.id = tab1.id
                         OR tab2.name = tab1.name;
```

And before your next edit to your question also includes different moods for a corresponding id name pair, this is how you'd get the "first" (But first means any first in any order the DBMS uses while executing the query. You'd need a column to define the order to have that deterministic.)

```
SELECT tab1.id,
       tab1.name,
       coalesce((SELECT TOP 1
                        tab2.mood
                        FROM tab2
                        WHERE tab2.id = tab1.id),
                (SELECT TOP 1
                        tab2.mood
                        FROM tab2
                        WHERE tab2.name = tab1.name))
       FROM tab1;
```

(`TOP 1` is SQL Server syntax. I don't know which of the tags to your question is the actual DBMS you use. Consider correcting that.)

Comment: This will end with extra rows in outcome table with 2 entry for id 3

Comment: @AaronTan: See my edit. One way to eliminate duplicates is doing so in the joined table. But you could of course also do it on the result of the join.

Comment: The reason for the duplicate is due to the left join getting result for id 3 and John resulting in two rows. I get what you're trying to do but the problem still lies on the tab1 due to the 2 entries available in tab1 (3 and John).

Comment: @AaronTan: "2 entries available in tab1": You edited your question to include two identical rows in `tab2` not in `tab1`. The duplicates in `tab2` get removed prior the join in the subquery in my edited answer. But maybe you should take some time and think about what you really want and under which circumstances (duplicates, etc.) this is to be achieved. Than edit your question and include all that **in detail**.

Comment: thanks @sticky bit, second query seemed to be working when I try to do a count(*) with cte and it matches my tab1 count. However when I try to run it for the actual result on redash.io, I got "Error running query: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error". Do you have any idea on this? - I have also amended on the tags, I am currently using SQL server.

Comment: @AaronTan: I forgot a closing parenthesis, see my edit for the corrected version.

Comment: I fixed that in my query - the table I created is just a mock table. I suspect it's the platform I am running my sql are the one that comes with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to be a `left join`:

```
select distinct tab1.id, tab2.name, tab2.mood
from tab2 left join
     tab1
     on tab2.id = tab1.id
order by name;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/CELM79671) is a rextester showing the result.

Comment: This doesn't work for second entry where there's no id but only name as identifier

Comment: @AaronTan . . . Why not?  That one has no matching `id` in `tab1`, so it is blank -- just as in the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I think this gives you what you want, but if there is a lot of data it will be slow I think. Also, it doesn't cater for where there are duplicate ids with different emotions - it will return both emotions in that case.

```
SELECT distinct tab1.id, tab2.name, tab2.mood
FROM 
    tab1
    LEFT JOIN tab2 ON 
        CASE WHEN tab1.id IS NOT NULL THEN tabl.id ELSE tab1.name END
      = CASE WHEN tab1.id IS NOT NULL THEN tab2.id ELSE tab2.name END
```